# Nuget Class Libraries vs Local Class Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have setup our internal class libraries to be built in VSTS and to create nuget package hosted in our VSTS upon each successful build.
Our application then references those class libraries by downloading the nuget package off of our own VSTS url.

If we want to make changes to our class library we modify the solution, increment the assembly number, rebuild it online and a new nuget package will replace the existing one.  Then update our application with the latest package.

Now because the class library is referenced through nuget in the application, what would be the best strategy to test changes made to the class library at the application level?

1. Should I remove the nuget package, reference the library locally then test, then re-add nuget reference?
2. Should I just create a new package each time and come up with an internal policy with other developers when it comes to managing assembly version numbers to only use specific assembly versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with option 2 - generate a pre-release nuget package.

> "A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a
>   series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch
>   version" (http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html)

Comment: By doing this I won't be able to debug the class library though right?

Comment: You can include symbols in your nuget package to help debugging.